# Parallel Computing in Matlab: can't find a network unit/folder

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, network-programming

I want to run a code on a cluster of several PCs using as current directory a common logical unit, that I called `Q:\`. The correct path to this folder is, say,

```
 \\myserver\myfolder
```

so I'm starting the parallel script with

```
spmd
    cd('\\myserver\myfolder')
  end
```

and, to be sure, I even put the folder in "AdditionalPaths" in the Properties of the Cluster Profile.

To check whether the functions and the files are reachable I use

```
spmd
    check('function1')
  end
```

where "function1" is a function m-file in "myfolder". Unfortunately `spmd` can't find the function on every PC, but just on a few of them, with no apparent reason of choice. I already checked in the issued computers if the "SYSTEM" user account (used by matlabpool) has permission to  "\myserver\myfolder", but it always has.

Anybody encountered a similar situation?

P.S: I'm using on every computer in the cluster R2012a on Windows 7 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

The 'additionalPaths' setting in the cluster profile applies to cluster jobs created and associated with that profile. A job needs to be created using 'parcluster(cluster_profile)' per [this example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/share-code-with-the-workers.html), where cluster_profile is the name of the cluster profile that you have assigned the `additionalPaths` variable.

Also for robustness you can try also adding the `AdditionalFiles` option with the .m files needed and the path command can be added to the startup files for the worker (e.g. `jobStartup.m`, `taskStartup.m`) to ensure that every worker can see the path.

Comment: Thanks, but I managed to solve this by using a different server. Probably it was a permission problem.